# Quantum Circuit, example of the Bernstein-Vazirani problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

This question is regarding the quantum circuit in the picture below.

Suppose we have the set up below, where U performs the operation $U:\mid x \rangle \mid y \rangle \rightarrow \mid x \rangle\mid y \oplus f(x) \rangle$.

We define the function $f(x)$ on the 3-bit string $\mid x \rangle= \mid x_1 x_2 x_3 \rangle$ with $f(x)=a\cdot x=a_1 x_1 \oplus a_2 x_2 \oplus a_3 x_3$, where $\oplus$ is addition modulo 2 and $a$ is the fixed three bit string $\mid a \rangle=\mid a_1 a_2 a_3 \rangle$.

The objective is to show how this circuit finds $a$.

So far I have that the 3 zero qubits pass through 3 Hadamard gates, putting them in the bell state $\beta_{00}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\mid 0 \rangle +\mid 1 \rangle)$. So at point 1 on the circuit the system has state:

$$\frac14(\mid 0 \rangle +\mid 1 \rangle)(\mid 0 \rangle +\mid 1 \rangle)(\mid 0 \rangle +\mid 1 \rangle)(\mid 0 \rangle -\mid 1 \rangle)=\frac14 \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^3} \mid x \rangle(\mid 0 \rangle -\mid 1 \rangle$$

Where we have found the RHS by expanding out and summing over all the possible 3 but qubits.

So next we consider what happens when the system passes through the $U$ gate, we find:

$$\frac14 \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^3} \mid x \rangle(\mid f(x) \rangle -\mid 1 \oplus f(x) \rangle )$$

Here we notice that is $f(x)$ is $0$ nothing changes, but if it is $1$ it acts as a factor of $-1$, therefore the system is:

$$\frac14 \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^3} (-1)^{f(x)}\mid x \rangle(\mid 0 \rangle -\mid 1  \rangle )$$

Now $f(x)$ outputs sums of the elements of $a$ depending on the value of $x$, for example for $\mid x \rangle = \mid 110 \rangle$, $f(x)=f(110)=a_1 \oplus a_2$. Would anyone be able to help me understand how this helps us find the three values for $a$ at our measured gates? The main issue i'm finding is finding a useful of writing an expression for the system after it has passed through the last three Hadamard gates, one which we can use to find $a$, any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the action of the second set of Hadamards.

Your state at stage 2 is, as you say,
$$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}\ket{\psi_2}=\frac1{2^{n/2}}\sum_x (-1)^{f(x)}\ket{x}\ket{-}.$$
Applying the Hadamards will take this to
$$\ket{\psi_3}=\frac1{2^{n/2}}\sum_x (-1)^{f(x)}H^{\otimes n}\ket{x}\ket{-}
=\frac1{2^{n/2}}\sum_x (-1)^{f(x)}\ket{(-)^{x_1}}\cdots\ket{(-)^{x_n}}\ket{-},$$
i.e.
$$\ket{\psi_3}=\frac1{2^{n}}\sum_x (-1)^{f(x)}\sum_y(-1)^{x\cdot y}\ket{y}\ket{-}.$$

The probability amplitude of measuring the state $\ket{y}$ is then 
$$a(y)=\frac1{2^{n}}\sum_x (-1)^{f(x)}(-1)^{x\cdot y}=\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+(-1)^{a_j\oplus y_j}\right),$$
which vanishes unless $y=a$.

Thus for linear $f$, the complicated wave created by its unitary $U$ will be made by the Hadamards to re-interfere into a product state that allows a direct read-out of $f$.

Comment: Thank you for this, it is great, just working out exactly what you mean. What do you mean by $N$ & $H^{\otimes N}$, we are applying $H\otimes H\otimes H\otimes 1$ to the system correct? So can we just write $N=3$? Also some of the elements of $x$ are $0$ which will be taken to $\ket{+}$?

Comment: Yes, $N=3$. The [tensor power notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_powers_and_braiding) is right. Under $H$, $|0\rangle$ goes to $|+\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ goes to $|-\rangle$, so $|x_j\rangle$ goes to $|(-1)^{x_j}\rangle$.

Comment: Ok, great, so I guess your description was a general one.
So wrt to your second statement, wouldn't $|(-1)^{x_j}\rangle=\ket{0}$ or $\ket{-1}$ not $\ket{+}$ or $\ket{-}$?, so our three string vector $\ket{x}=\ket{x_1 x_2 x_3}$ would go to a product of some combination of $\ket{+}$ and $\ket{-}$ under the Hadamard gate?

Comment: No. $(-)^0=+$ and $(-)^1=-$. And yes, $|x\rangle$ goes to a combination of $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$'s as shown. You then decompose this into the computational basis $\{|y\rangle\}$ to get the final measurement amplitudes. You need to spend (far) more time going through the derivation in detail.

Comment: $\ket{-}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\ket{0}-\ket{1}) \Rightarrow (\ket{-})^0=(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\ket{0}-\ket{1}))^0$, I don't see how this equals $\ket{+}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\ket{0}+\ket{1})$? Wouldn't it be $\Big(\begin{matrix}
  1 \\
  1  
 \end{matrix} \Big)=\sqrt2 \ket{+}$?

Comment: This comment thread is too long and I'm losing interest in doing your homework. Confusing $|(-)^0\rangle$ and $|-\rangle^0$ is wasting people's time. This is all just a notational shorthand for the action of $H$. Unless you sit down and do all of the derivation in my answer, in full, and make a reasonable effort at understanding it, it is pointless to keep discussing.

Comment: I did not realise this was simply notational shorthand for $H$ as I had not encountered it before.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain the last part in a simple way:

$\frac14 \sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^3} \mid x \rangle(\mid 0 \rangle -\mid 1 \rangle$

equals

$ |s_{1} s_{2} s_{3} \rangle \otimes |- \rangle$

where each $s_i$ is either $|+ \rangle$ or $|- \rangle$, depending on whether $a_{i}$ is $0$ or $1$.

Hence, you can read each bit of $a$ by measuring the $|s_{1} s_{2} s_{3} \rangle$ in the Hadamard basis.